# Realbasic widget similar to workflow view in automator

Tags: listview, widget, automator, realbasic

Is there any kind of RealBasic/Real Studio widget which looks similar to the workflow view in Automator or GameSalad?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing out there that I know of.  But the way to do it is to subclass the canvas control.  I suggest you take a look at the Custom Frames example at http://homepage.mac.com/alexrestrepo/indexmain.html is it will give you some decent ideas on how to do that and have 'objects' in the canvas.